# Find the most optimal solution for sorting data organized in arrays and in AVL trees

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity, avl-tree

This is a following practice problem I have for my exams in data structures. We want to get the sorted sequence of integers from two sets of numbers A and B of size n each.

1. A and B are organized into arrays that are not sorted.
2. A and B are organized into arrays of which only the first is sorted.
3. A and B are organized into AVL trees.

In each case I want the result to be stored in another array C of size 2*n.

For the 1st case I thought simply copy all the elements into the second array which will take O(2n) and then use quick sort to sort them all together which will take O(2nlog2n).

For the second case is there a quicker way or should I just copy and sort them all together as before?

Also I have no idea how to proceed on the third case.

Comment: For the second case, can't you sort the array B, which is unsorted array in nlogn time and then apply merge two sorted arrays A and B algorithm on it. For the third case, just apply tree traversal on the tree and keep storing the elements of the array in a list and then sort the list.

Comment: So for the third case apply in order tree traversal for the first tree And copy to an array And apply in order tree traversal for the second tree And copy to another array And then merge the two sorted arrays A And B. Does That sound right??

Comment: That sounds about right, yes exactly. The total time complexity will be O(n) at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your solution is asymptotically optimum.
2. Sort B in place. Then do a simple merge of the two lists into the final list. Complexity is O(n log n) to sort the B array, and O(2n) for the merge.
3. Start non-recursive inorder traversals of both trees, using an explicit stack to maintain state, and merge into the single output array. The complexity is O(2n).

For non-recursive inorder tree traversal, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/

Basically, you modify that code to create a `tree_traversal` class that has methods:

- isAtEnd - returns true if you've traversed the entire tree
- peek - returns the current item in the tree
- next - moves to the next item in the tree

Instantiate an inorder traversal for each tree, and then do a standard merge. Something like:

```
a = new int[2*n]; // allocate output array
ix = 0; // output index
t1 = new tree_traversal(tree_a);
t2 = new tree_traversal(tree_b);
while (!t1.isAtEnd() && !t2.isAtEnd())
{
    if (t1.peek() < t2.peek())
    {
        a[ix] = t1.peek();
        t1.next();
    }
    else
    {
        a[ix] = t2.peek();
        t2.next();
    }
    ++ix;
}
// at this point, you've reached the end of one tree
// empty the other
while (!t1.isAtEnd())
{
    a[ix] = t1.peek();
    t1.next();
    ++ix;
}
while (!t2.isAtEnd())
{
    a[ix] = t2.peek();
    t2.next();
    ++ix;
}
```